# Dynamic Upload file to FTP

Tags: linux

I have a command which produces different files after every 10 or so min.

I want to upload those files to FTP server. If files from command1 is stored locally then I can upload them later. But I do not want to create files locally.

e.g. After executing **command1**, it produces files namely file1, file2 and so on.
If this command had produced single file then I could have executed:

```
command1 | ftpput -u user -p pass 192.168.1.1 remote_file local_file
```

Is there any way to upload dynamically generated files to FTP server ?

Comment: `curl` with the `--upload-file=-` option, perhaps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the *fuse* filesystem **curlftpfs** to mount the remote
filesystem in the directory your command is creating files in. 
Then new files will be transparently written (by curl ftp commands) to the remote. See `man curlftpfs`.

For example, if your command creates files in  `/a/b/` then

```
$ curlftpfs -o user=user:pass 192.168.1.1 /a/b
```

mounts the remote at `/a/b`. An `ls /a/b` will list the files at the top of the remote ftp directory.
Note there are restrictions (due to the ftp protocol) on what you can do to the local files, for example you cannot append to a file.

Comment: **Brilliant !**  Wasn't aware of this command.